# Django CMS app-hook - how to set title?

Tags: django, django-cms

I have app-hook for my Django CMS 3.0.3 and looking for right solution to set meta title to my app-hook pages.

Now I'm doing it like so: in my base template:

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags menu_tags staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    {% block head %}
        <title>{% page_attribute 'page_title' %}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{% page_attribute 'meta_description' %}">
    {% endblock head %}
    ...
```

In my app-hook templates I overrided this `block head` like so:

```
{% block head %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
{% endblock head %}
```

Is it a right solution? Maybe I should somehow change attribute `page_title` in my app-hook's views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer there : [Django CMS Page Title Doesn't Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077543/django-cms-page-title-doesnt-render?answertab=active#tab-top)

It looks like you did quite the same, so I guess it is the best solution